# Apache ProxyRemote does nothing

Tags: security, proxy

On Ubuntu server 18.04 running Apache 2.4, I'd like to pass all Apache's outgoing requests to a forward proxy so that I can filter out some URLs for security reasons (using [Tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/)).

It seems that Apache's [ProxyRemote](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote) directive in my Vhost config should do this, so I've used the following:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyRemote * http://localhost:8888
```

I have also tried adding environment variables to /etc/environment, like this:

```
http_proxy="http://localhost:8888/"
https_proxy="http://localhost:8888/"
```

I can then see other applications now using the proxy, for example (from Tinyproxy's logs):

```
CONNECT   Jul 28 17:26:58 [2318]: Request (file descriptor 7): CONNECT api.snapcraft.io:443 HTTP/1.1
CONNECT   Jul 28 17:26:58 [2315]: Request (file descriptor 7): CONNECT api.snapcraft.io:443 HTTP/1.1
```

But not Apache. It still passes all its outbound requests to ports 80 and 443 directly. How can I get Apache to use the proxy?

---

**EDIT**: I've just seen this duplicate [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493574/configure-apache-web-server-to-use-a-proxy-server), so I assume I'm trying to do the right thing. But how?

Comment: Are mod_proxy_http and mod_proxy_connect modules loaded?

Comment: `ProxyRequests On` ?

Comment: @suspectus `a2enmod proxy_http proxy_connect` says the are already loaded. I think `ProxyRequests On` might be dangerous perhaps, but it seems to make no difference. I'm sure there's something obvious that I'm not doing but I can't think what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read the Apache docs again, and thought about the fact that it says `ProxyRemote` "*defines remote proxies to this proxy*." This implies that Apache has to be proxying requests already and you want to use an upstream proxy. So it may not be what I want after all.

So instead, I looked at using environment variables, which appear to work more in the way I wanted:

Putting this in `/etc/apache2/envvars` makes most (but not all?) apps hosted by Apache use the proxy:

```
export http_proxy='http://localhost:8888'
export https_proxy='http://localhost:8888'
```

And putting this in `/etc/environment`, means other apps will go via the proxy too if they are configured to use those envvars:

```
http_proxy="http://localhost:8888/"
https_proxy="http://localhost:8888/"
```

I see that now both outgoing port 80 and 443 are going through the proxy. Hooray.

---

I currently use iptables to force all port 80 outgoing via Tinyproxy:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m owner ! --uid-owner tinyproxy -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888
```

But given the above, I might even be able to block port 443, since anything not using the envvars is probably dodgy.